# Getting error, "conflicting types for '_'" in C. Sorry to ask this again, I'm either not understanding or something else is wrong

Tags: c

I've looked into what this error means, and as far as I can tell, it means there is conflicts with the name of the function I am trying to call (the name already being taken by another function, thus creating confusion). However, my error persists even when I change the function name.

Now, you might think I just suck at naming things originally or I simply have bad luck, but I've renamed this function about 5 times, using more and more specific names each time. Right now its "final_distancexxxx" and its still giving me that error.

This is the setup of the functions I have:

```
float final_distancexxxx (float max_v, float a, float t){
    float d = 0;
    float t_max = 0;
    max_v = 0;
    a = 0;
    t = 0;

    t_max = max_v/a;

    if (t>t_max)
        d = (max_v/2)*t_max+(t-t_max)*max_v;
    else
        d = ((t*a)/2)*t;
    return d;
}

main (){
    float d = 0;
    float max_v = 0;
    float a = 0;
    float t = 0;
    float t_max = 0;
    float max_v2 = 0;
    float a2 = 0;
    float d_final = 0;
    float d_final2 = 0;

    printf("Please input acceleration for vehicle 1: ");
    scanf("%f", & a);
    printf("Please input max velocity for vehicle 1: ");
    scanf ("%f", & max_v);
    printf("Please input acceleration for vehicle 2: ");
    scanf("%f", & a2);
    printf("Please input max velocity for vehicle 2: ");
    scanf ("%f", & max_v2);
    printf ("Please enter race time: ");
    scanf ("%f", t);

    float final_distancexxxx (max_v, a, t);
    d_final = d;

    printf ("%f, ", d_final);
}
```

Please disregard any other mistakes I might have, I just want to fix this error and try to figure the rest of it out.

Comment: What is the line `float final_distancexxxx (max_v, a, t);` doing inside your `main` function?

Comment: Not relevant to your problem, but `main()` should be `int main(void)`.

Answer (score 4):

This problem has nothing to do with your function name. You have an extra `float` on this line:

```
float final_distancexxxx (max_v, a, t);
```

Delete it.  You probably meant:

```
d = final_distancexxxx (max_v, a, t);
```

Comment: And assign the result to `d`, I presume.

Comment: Yeah.  I just read some more of the program, and I'd agree.  Editing now.

Answer (score 1):

The variable "d" in your function `final_distancexxxx` has a different scope than the one in `main`; they do not represent the same location in memory. So even if this compiled, when you say `d_final = d`, the variable `d` is uninitialized.

What you want to do is store the return value of the function:

```
d_final = final_distancexxxx (max_v, a, t);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
float final_distancexxxx (max_v, a, t);
```

This, in `main()`, is considered as function declaration and not invocation .

Here, compiler takes `final_distancexxxx` as declaration of function that takes **int** variables `max_v, a, t` as arguments which conflicts with your function definition `float final_distancexxxx (float max_v, float a, float t){..}` and so the error.

Change it just as,

```
final_distancexxxx (max_v, a, t);
```

Or assign the return value to some variable.

Answer (score 0):

change

```
float final_distancexxxx (max_v, a, t);
d_final = d;
```

to

```
 d_final = final_distancexxxx (max_v, a, t);
```

Answer (score 0):

remove the float keyword at the time of function call!
compiler sees it as a declaration
and gives a **multiple declaration error** that do not match !

`final_distancexxxx (max_v, a, t);` -> **function call**

`float final_distancexxxx (max_v, a, t);` **function declaration**

use the first one in main!

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't declare a function in `main()`

```
float final_distancexxxx (max_v, a, t);
```

`float` is return type and you should use it if you want your function to return a float value but OUTSIDE main,

```
d_final = final_distancexxxx (max_v, a, t);
```

is I guess what you want like others suggested, you have to assign the function to a `float` variable, because it has a return value of `float`, if it was `void` for example then you didn't need to assign the function to a variable because it has not return value.

Have a look at http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iOS5sPivuJA (it's an 8-minute video titled "C Programming Tutorial - 11 - Into to Functions").

Comment: You certainly *can* declare a function in `main`; you just have to do it correctly. If that's supposed to be a declaration, it should be `float final_distancexxxx (float max_v, float a, float t);` or `float final_distancexxxx (float, float, float);`, which is legal and redundant. But it appears that it's *intended* to be a call, so dropping the `float` keyword should solve the problem.

Comment: @KeithThompson That would be the prototype only and he has to type it in the very beginning I meant `float myfunction(int i){do something}` with the body is not possible in main but you are right declaration means prototype, I used wrong keyword and corrected cant to shouldnt.

Comment: Of course, if you *declare* a function inside `main`, you still have to *define* it elsewhere (which the OP's code already does, so that wasn't the issue). Incidentally, not all function declarations are prototypes; `float final_distancexxxx();` is a valid declaration, but not a prototype. But the real point, I think, is that the OP never meant that line to be a declaration at all; he meant it to be a *call*, and incorrectly preceded it with the `float` keyword -- which is why the compiler assumed it was a declaration. Error messages can be misleading if the compiler can't infer your intent.